# PHP - show variable in while loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I have while loop in a PHP file and outside of that, I have one variable. When I try to add this variable into while, it doesn't work.

example code:

```
<?

$var1 = 2999288;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $var1;

}

?>
```

Can anybody tell me a solution, how to echo that variable into a while? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the variable is not `echo`ing, then you're DB Query probably isn't returning any results. Before the loop do a: `echo mysql_affected_rows($db);`

Comment: Try echo "hello" instead of echo $var and see if its echoing.

Comment: I'm with @Jasper on this one.  The only reason for this to not work is that your query either did not work or did not return any results.  Adding error handling and checking for edge cases when writing your code would reveal this.

Comment: it seems that $result has a value false so check your sql query

Comment: Thank you guys! :D while wasn't returning nothing... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query is not returning any rows, make sure that your query is working properly before echoing results.  Also please look into prepared SQL statements, they are more safe than the traditional way that you are using.

Comment: There's nothing he's posted that says he's not using prepared statements or at least not parameterizing his inputs.  A real concern is that mysql_* is deprecated and he should use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: You are right, I assumed he wasn't using prepared statements since he was using mysql_*.